# Azure DNS - Terraform - Ignore TXT Value

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have some terrform code which works, but i want to able to ignore the DNS TXT Record value as this is updated externally using another tool (acme.sh), I have tried multiple differnt types of HCL to ignore the value, the terraform HCL does not fail, just set's the value back to the original value

Any help would be appreciated.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "mydomain-co-uk-dns" {
  name     = "mydomain.co.uk-dns"
  location = "North Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "mydomaindns" {
  name                = "mydomain.co.uk"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mydomain-co-uk.name
}


resource "azurerm_dns_txt_record" "_acme-challenge-api" {
  name                = "_acme-challenge.api"
  zone_name           = azurerm_dns_zone.mydomaindns.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mydomain-co-uk-dns.name
  ttl                 = 300
  record {
    value = "randomkey-that-changes externally"
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "acmesh"
  }
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      record
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "but with not luck" - is not specific. Exactly what did you do? What errors did you get? What's wrong with the current code?

Comment: No error, it dosn't ignore the new value, so if i make a change to the value in the portal manually, when i run terraform again it set the value back to the original.

Comment: @Iain Did you create `_acme-challenge-api` via Terraform too? Is it already being managed by Terraform? Or is this entire block brand new?

Comment: May I please know the terraform version that you are using @lain?

Comment: @Eemiya, I am using Terraform to manage the entry, i actually used terraform import to reverse engineer the entries i already had

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT, I am using terraform 1.0.7 and azurerm providers 2.70.0, I will try updating to the latest

Comment: Sure @lain..let me know if it works out .

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT, after you sucess, i tried running the sample code, which was subset of what i have in production, I found it worked too.  I then tried deleting the entries i had within the portal and got terraform to redeploy and thats got it working. :) Thanks I really appriciate it.

Comment: Glad to be of help @lain .. will post the same as answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried testing using the same code that you have provided and was successfully able to deploy the resources , then manually changed the value of record for portal and applied the terraform code again and it didn't do any changes just changed the value of the previous record to the newer value changes from portal in the terraform state file.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** I used Terraform `v1.0.5` on `windows_amd64` + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/`azurerm v2.83.0`.

As confirmed by @Lain , the issue was resolved after upgrading the `azurerm` from `2.70.0` to `latest`.